# Table of contents not showing header and footer

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

My Table of Contents page is not showing the headers/footers—why is this happening?

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{printlen}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
%preamble
\usepackage[
  height=8.5in,      % height of the text block
  width=6.5in,       % width of the text block
  top=78pt,        % distance of the text block from the top of the page
  headheight=60pt, % height for the header block
  headsep=12pt,    % distance from the header block to the text block
  heightrounded,   % ensure an integer number of lines
  %showframe,       % show the main blocks
  verbose,         % show the values of the parameters in the log file
]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                      %for color of table
\usepackage{booktabs}                        %for toprule midrule bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{multirow} % Required for multirows
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}                             %no hyphenation
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lastpage}                                     %toget last page number
 \usepackage{indentfirst}
 \usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, matrix, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,quotes,positioning}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=blue!20]
\tikzstyle{eff} = [ellipse,  minimum height=2em,  draw=black, fill=pink!20]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,  ->, >=stealth]
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,calc}
%header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize Prepared in \LaTeX\ Typeset By\\
Colonel JS Bibra\\
Joint Controller\\
Management Representative / CQA(AVL)
 }
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize  Approved for Issue By\\
S Satish Chandra Kumar\\
Controller\\
CQA(AVL) 
}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image-a}} 
\fancyhead[C]{\footnotesize 
                Quality Management System Manual \\ ISO 9001:2015 \\ Controllerate of Quality Assurance \\ Armoured Vehicle Electronics\\Avadi, Chennai – 600 054}
\fancyhead[R]{%
    \footnotesize 
            Issue No        : \hspace{35pt}02                   \\ 
                Issue Date  : 15 Sep 2019            \\ 
    Rev No/ Rev Date\hspace{0pt}        : \hspace{36pt}00                       \\ 
                Page        : \hspace{23pt}\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\renewcommand\headrule{%------------fancy top line of page
\vspace{-6pt}
\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}
{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}%
\hrulefill}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
%-----------------------------------------
%---------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%title page
\begin{titlepage}
\rule{3mm}{.5pt}%
    \rule[-3mm]{.5pt}{1cm}%
    \rule{3mm}{.5pt}%
    \fontfamily{stix}\selectfont
\pagecolor{brown!20}
\begin{center}
\headrule\\[.25in]
 {\MakeUppercase {\huge Quality Management System Manual}}\\[2mm]
\headrule\\[4mm]
\textsc{\Large as per requirements of std iso 9001:2015}    \\[4mm]
                                        \begin{figure}[H]
                                        \centering
                                        \includegraphics[scale=.4]{../../images/dgqalogo1.jpg} 
                                        \label{DGQA Logo}
                                        \end{figure}
\vspace*{4em}
\textsc{\normalsize CONTROLLERATE OF QUALITY ASSURANCE\\ARMOURED VEHICLE ELECTRONICS\\GOVERNMENT OF INDIA\\ MIN OF DEFENCE (DGQA)\\AVADI, CHENNAI -- 600 054\\tel: 044-26843007, fax: 044-26841881, email:} {\normalsize  <!-- e --><a href="mailto:cqaavl-dgqa@nic.in">cqaavl-dgqa@nic.in</a><!-- e -->}\\ 
\vfill
\line(1,0){400}\\
\scriptsize NOT TO BE COPIED OR REPRODUCED IN FULL OR PART WITHOUT PERMISSION OF CONTROLLER, CQA(AVL)
\end{center}
\rule{3mm}{.5pt}%
    \rule[-3mm]{.5pt}{1cm}%
    \rule{3mm}{.5pt}%
\end{titlepage}
%****************************************************************************************************

 \pagenumbering{roman}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section*{Distribution List for Quality Manual}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Distribution List for Quality Manual}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{p{.5in}p{3in}p{2in}}

\toprule

\midrule
COPY NO & DISTRIBUTION & TYPE OF COPY\\
\midrule
1 & Management representative & Master Copy\\
2 & Controller Secretariat & Controlled Copy\\
3 & T Division & Controlled Copy\\
4 & M Division & Controlled Copy\\
5 & Admin & Controlled Copy\\
6 & Stores & Controlled Copy\\
7 & Library & Controlled Copy \\
8 & P \&\ C & Controlled Copy\\
9 & Quality Audit Section & Controlled Copy\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table} \cleardoublepage
%-----------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%table of contents stuff%
\tableofcontents

\thispagestyle{empty}%no page number on toc%
\cleardoublepage%pagebreak after toc%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%list of figures
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}List of Figures}
\cleardoublepage%pagebreak after list of figures%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%main body stuff%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
%toc
%abbreviation
%figures
%tables
%annexures
%main content

\section{Scope}\label{sec:Scope}
CQA(AVL) shall provide quality assurance activities for armored fighting vehicles (AFV) and there variants as per Directorate General of Quality Assurance (DGQA) guidelines

\section{Normative Reference}\label{sec:Normative Reference}
\begin{quote}
                ISO 9001-2015   -- Quality management system requirements\\
                ISO 19011:2015  -- Guidelines for auditing management systems\\
                DGQA standing orders\\
                CQA(AVL) standing orders
\end{quote}


\section{Terms and Definitions}\label{sec:Terms and Definitions}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
ABBREVIATION                &           Acronym\\
\hline
AC & Assistant Controller\\

\end{tabular}
\cleardoublepage

\section{Leadership}
\subsection{Leadership and commitment}
\subsubsection{General}

\cleardoublepage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Annexures}
%-----------------------------------------------
\begin{center}
\hfill  \underline{{\textbf{Annexure : QMS/F-01}}}\\[1cm]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Flow Chart of Corrective Action: QMS/F-01 }
\raisebox{20pt}{\underline{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{flow chart of corrective action}}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (pro1)[process]{Non\\ Conformance Identified};
\node (pro2a)[process, below of =pro1, xshift=-5cm]{Service};
\node (pro2b)[process, below of =pro1]{Process};
\node (pro2c)[process, below of =pro1, xshift=5cm]{System};
\node (pro3)[process, below of =pro2b]{Investigation of Cause};
\node (pro4)[process, below of =pro3]{Corrective Action Plan};
\node (pro5)[process, below of =pro4]{Implementation of Action Plan};
\node (pro4a)[process, right of =pro4, xshift=3cm, yshift=-1cm]{Review of Plan, \\Action \&\ Effectiveness in Management Review Meeting};
\node (eff)[eff, below of = pro4a, yshift = -.5cm]{Check Effectiveness};
\node (pro4b)[process, below of = pro4a, yshift = -2cm]{Is it OK?};
\node (pro4c)[process, below of = pro4b]{Close};
\draw [arrow](pro1)--(pro2b);
\draw [arrow](pro1)--(pro2a);
\draw [arrow](pro1)--(pro2c);
\draw [arrow](pro2b)--(pro3);
\draw [arrow](pro3)--(pro4);
\draw [arrow](pro4)--(pro5);
\draw [arrow] (pro2a) |- ($(pro2b)!.5!(pro3)$);
\draw [arrow] (pro2c) |- ($(pro2b)!.5!(pro3)$);
\draw [arrow] (eff) -- (pro4b);
\draw [arrow] (pro4b) -- (pro4c);
\draw [arrow](pro5)|-(eff);
\draw[arrow](1.5,-6)--(3.5,-6);
\draw[arrow](1.5,-8)--(3.5,-8);
\draw[arrow](3.5,-11)--(-5,-11)|-(-1.5,-4);
\node [align=left] at (2.6,-11.2) {Not OK};
\node [align=left] at (5.5,-12) {OK};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\cleardoublepage6
%-------------------------------
\begin{center}
\hfill  \underline{{\textbf{Annexure : QMS/F-03}}}\\[1cm]
 \underline{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{Minutes of Management Review meeting }}}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Minutes of Management Review Meeting: QMS/F-03 }
\end{center}
\paragraph{Date:}
\paragraph{Member Present:}
\paragraph{Members Absent:}
\paragraph{Agenda:}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\roman{enumii})}
            \begin{enumerate}
\item The status of actions from previous management reviews
            \end{enumerate}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.5in}|p{3in}|p{1.6in}|p{1in}|}
\toprule
S No & Details of Discussion and Action Planned & Responsibility & Target Date\\ 
\midrule
1 &  & &\\
2 &  & &\\
3 &  & & \\
4 &  & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table} 
    \vspace{1cm}
(Signature of MR) \hspace{3in} (Signature of Controller)\\
%---------------------------------
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this is a **minimal** working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is happening because after the `\tableofcontents` command you have added

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Put

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

there instead.

Comment: got it now--the pagestyle comment was an error on my part